# Error Unable to setup base domain mappings for serverless custom domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless, aws-serverless, custom-domain

In serverless.yml, under custom, I have the following code (with dummy values here):

```
customDomain:
    domainName: myhost.mydomain.com
    basePath: ''
    stage: ${self:provider:stage}
    createRouteS3Record: true
    endpointType: 'edge'
    securityPolicy: tls_1_2
    certificateArn: 'arn:aws:acm:.................'
    hostZoneId: 'P4OCK4S1PSTZK'
```

when I execute serverless deploy, everything goes smooth. the Api get generated properly for my function.
(Under functions i have `events: http`)

However after the API getting generated lambda getting deployed, I get the following error:

```
Error: Error: Unable to setup base domain mappings for myhost.mydomain.com
```

i do not get much info other than https://forum.serverless.com/t/error-unable-to-setup-base-domain-mappings/11395
Do not know how to include api versions in serverless if that is the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well small things can cause big problems and are very hard to figure out at times.
I found that `stage: ${self:provider:stage}` was wrong, it should have been `stage: ${self:provider.stage}`. The colon after provider was the culprit.

Answer (score 4):

I got this error after having a domain mapping, then removing it, then trying to add it again: it looks like Serverless doesn't completely remove a domain mapping.

I had to go to Custom domain names -> my domain -> API mappings -> Configure API mappings and manually delete the domain mapping before redeploying.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. In my serverless.yml file in events inside functions I was having 'httpApi'. Changing it to 'http' fixed my issue

```
functions:
 getWebHooks:
   handler: src/path
   events:
    - httpApi:
       path: /
```

to

```
functions:
 getWebHooks:
   handler: src/path
   events:
    - http:
       path: /
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting that error message because I (somehow) got the same api duplicated. so I went to

`API Gateway -> Custom domain name -> {name_of_my_domain} -> API Mappings -> Configure API Mappings`

Then I changed the API to use the correct API (holding the routes I was having in my app, and I could differentiate between both using their ID). Redeploying with Serverless succeeded